# Latest version of @polymer/paper-radio-button in npm registry

Tags: npm, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to work with **npm** Polymer package. I installed it by running

```
npm install @polymer/polymer
```

And I got the following

```
+ @polymer/polymer@2.6.0 
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 1.795s
```

Now in the same manner I'm trying to install **paper-radio-button**

```
npm install paper-radio-button
```

and the result is

```
+ paper-radio-button@0.3.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 1.358s
```

It looks like that for Polymer I really got the latest version. **But for paper-radio-button I got 0.3.0 version**. However https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-radio-button states that the latest version for paper-radio-button **is 2.1.0 and not 0.3.0**.

**How can I get the latest version of paper-radio-button if I use npm?**
The 0.3.0 functionality is weird so I cannot use it.

Thanks

Comment: For Polymer 2.X, you should install components with bower, not npm.

Comment: It's sad... Do you know where Polymer officially mentioned that despite the fact that Polymer 2.5 is published on npm the Polymer components are still on bower?

Comment: In the installation instructions: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/install-2-0  Polymer 3 will use npm (https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-08-22-npm-modules.html).